Use htaccess to redirect to a php file if argument exists, otherwise filter by IP
Currently, my IP filter works fine.
But I am needing to check for a specific URL argument before the filter runs and if that argument exists, skip the filter and redirect to specialHandler.php
As it is now, no matter what I do, it won't redirect or if it is redirecting, the IP filter is blocking.
Now, if I remove the IP filter, the redirect DOES work, so it does appear both work independently, just not together.
# First, check if 'mykey' parameter is present and route to specialHandler.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mykey=([^&]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ specialHandler.php [L,QSA]

# IP restrictions apply only if the above condition isn't met
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 111.111.111.111
Allow from 222.222.222.222
Allow from 333.333.333.333



"so it does appear both work independently" - yes, of course they do. The RewriteCond influences only the following RewriteRule, it doesn't affect directives provided by a completely different module altogether.

You could try and wrap your deny/allow configuration into an <If> that checks the query string, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

An alternative would be to place that redirection target in a separate directory and configure the IP filtering for that directory.
